# What's causing the error "Element type "xsi:" must be followed by either attribute specificatio ns, ">" or "/>"" here?

Tags: xml, xsd

Here PersonList  is the root tag. PersonList contains the entry of each person with adhaarno, name, age and address.

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PersonList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="PersonList.xsd">
    <Person>
        <adhaarno>414356782345</adhaarno>
        <name>
            <firstname>Zeenath</firstname>
        </name>
        <age>28</age>
        <address>
            <doorno>33</doorno>
            <street>Raidu Street</street>
            <city>coimbatore</city>
            <pincode>641039</pincode>
        </address>
    </Person>

    <Person Category="seniorcitizen">
        <adhaarno>414356782345</adhaarno>
        <name>
            <firstname>Simon</firstname>
        </name>
        <age>75</age>
        <address>
            <doorno>7</doorno>
            <street>Raja Street</street>
            <city>Chennai</city>
            <pincode>600005</pincode>
        </address>
    </Person>

    <Person>
        <adhaarno>414356782345</adhaarno>
        <name>
            <lastname>Varma</lastname>
        </name>
        <age>25</age>
        <address>
            <doorno>25</doorno>
            <street>cox street</street>
            <city>Bangalore</city>
            <pincode>560025</pincode>
        </address>
    </Person>
</PersonList>
```

For this, I wrote the following xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsi:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
        <xsi:element name="PersonList">
            <xsi:complexType>
                <xsi:element name="Person" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xsi:complexType>
                    <xsi:attribute name="Category" type="xsi:string" use="optional"/>
                        <xsi:sequence>
                            <xsi:element name="adhaarno" type="xsi:integer"/>
                            <xsi:element name="name">
                                <xsi:complexType>
                                    <xsi:choice>
                                        <xsi:element name="firstname" type="xsi:string"/>
                                        <xsi:element name="lastname" type="xsi:string"/>
                                    </xsi:choice>
                                </xsi:complexType>
                            <xsi:/element>
                            <xsi:element name="age" type="xsi:integer"/>
                            <xsi:element name="address">
                                <xsi:complexType>
                                    <xsi:sequence>
                                        <xsi:element name="doorno" type="xsi:integer"/>
                                        <xsi:element name="street" type="xsi:string"/>
                                        <xsi:element name="city" type="xsi:string"/>
                                        <xsi:element name="pincode" type="xsi:integer"/>
                                    </xsi:sequence>
                                </xsi:complexType>
                            </xsi:element>
                        </xsi:sequence>
                    </xsi:complexType>
                </xsi:element>
            </xsi:complexType>
        </xsi:element>
    </xsi:schema>
```

After running the xsd, in the respective platform, I got this error:

```
Exception: Element type "xsi:" must be followed by either attribute specificatio ns, ">" or "/>". 
false
```

Although, I am aware of what usually causes this error, please help me troubleshoot the cause of this in the xsd, provided.

Answer (score 0):

The XSD has quite a few errors.

(1) It is not well-formed.

(2) I fixed the namespace and its prefix.

(3) Added a missing sequence under the root element.

(4) Pushed the attribute definition to its proper location.

> XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="PersonList">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="Person" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xsd:complexType>

                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="adhaarno" type="xsd:integer"/>
                            <xsd:element name="name">
                                <xsd:complexType>
                                    <xsd:choice>
                                        <xsd:element name="firstname" type="xsd:string"/>
                                        <xsd:element name="lastname" type="xsd:string"/>
                                    </xsd:choice>
                                </xsd:complexType>
                            </xsd:element>
                            <xsd:element name="age" type="xsd:integer"/>
                            <xsd:element name="address">
                                <xsd:complexType>
                                    <xsd:sequence>
                                        <xsd:element name="doorno" type="xsd:integer"/>
                                        <xsd:element name="street" type="xsd:string"/>
                                        <xsd:element name="city" type="xsd:string"/>
                                        <xsd:element name="pincode" type="xsd:integer"/>
                                    </xsd:sequence>
                                </xsd:complexType>
                            </xsd:element>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:attribute name="Category" type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your schema is in the wrong namespace. It should be "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" rather than "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance". You can use any namespace prefix you like: "xs" and "xsd" are the usual choices, while "xsi" is allowed but likely to confuse your readers.

But the answer to the specific question relating to the error message is that in the middle of your "schema" you have

```
<xsi:/element>
```

which is plainly broken.

Comment: Hey, I used the  "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" namespace because, it is referred in the xml file. Is there anything wrong there? (and thanks, I totally missed the xsi:element mistake.)

Comment: You seem to have completely missed the point about what namespaces are for. An element with local name "schema" is not an XSD Schema unless the namespace is `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema`.